# How easy is it to obtain a visa on arrival for Ghana?

Tags: visas, applications, italian-citizens, ghana, dutch-residents

Although I am an EU national currently (Italian) staying in another EU state (Netherlands), I am having some difficulty obtaining a visa for Ghana (because I am staying here temporarily, and have not registered as a permanent resident).

Under these circumstances, would I qualify for a visa on arrival in Ghana? What do I need to do to obtain one?

Having obtained a visa in exactly the same circumstances without difficulty last year from the embassy here, I was caught out this time when problems were raised with my application.

Comment: Was your visa application refused, or did the embassy reject it for processing?

Comment: It has not been refused; we are having some on-going discussions about whether I can obtain a residence registration in time.

Comment: Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b says: “Passengers with a confirmation given by the Ghana Immigration Service can obtain a visa on arrival. The passenger's reservation must have an "OK TO BOARD" message. An Emergency Visa on arrival letter issued by Ghana Immigration service will be issued to the passenger or directly to the airline personnel in Ghana when issued at short notice.” I do not know if this would apply to you or if the Embassy you’re dealing with can/would issue such a letter.

Comment: Not recommended to rely on but as NZ nationals we had no local consulate to apply to before travel. Our visa was granted upon arrival and the transfer of a crisp USD$20 note. As an aside, we were accused of being Nigerian spies (?!) on the way out and had an official scribble all over or bags with chalk, we assume he was trying to extort a similar bribe. By that time we were well worn and weary of this behaviour (scam artists in Accra and prior to this Addid Abbaba) we simply denied his claim and walked through ignoring him. (It worked!)